# problem with execute command on multiple servers using php and bash on linux server

Tags: php, linux, bash

I'm setting up new app and want to execute script on all my servers (actually is 16). What I doing wrong?

my bash file:

```
for (( c=1; c<=16; c++ ))
do
URL="http://s$c.domain.com/api.php?script=$scriptl&a1=$port&a2=$AUTHKEY"
screen -dmS apprun$c wget -q $URL #for faster exec bash script i run on screen
done
;;
esac
```

my api.php:

```
<?php
if(isset ( $_GET['script']) ) {
    $script = $_GET['script'];
    $port = $_GET['a1'];
    $cmd = "cd /home/scripts/ && perl $script $port"; 
    shell_exec($cmd);
}
```

I expect to run all app instant and run on all server but now some instances run perfect and some dont run never, what can i change to speed this and fix?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell, because there is no error message for the servers which won't run it. These machines might not have `perl` installed and therefore cannot interpret the script... or the script to run might be missing. Connect through `ssh` and try to run it manually - then you should see why it fails.